# Evaluate $\int\;\frac {x^m\ln(x)}{\cos(x)}dx$

Tags: integration

**Question:**

> How to Evaluate Integral $$\int\;\frac {x^m\ln(x)}{\cos(x)^2}\mathrm{d}x$$

**My suggestion**
$$F(x)=\int\;\frac {x^m\ln(x)}{\cos(x)^2}\mathrm{d}x$$

> integration by part

> let $$\mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{\cos(x)^2} \; \; v = x^m\ln(x)\\ \implies  u =\tan(x) \; \; \mathrm{d}v = x^{m-1}(m\ln(x)+1)$$

$$F(x)=x^m\ln(x)\tan(x)-\int x^{m-1}\tan(x)(m\ln(x)+1)\mathrm{d}x$$

**Help please**

Comment: Where did this come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of functions do not have an elementary antiderivative. Here, there is no antiderivative expressible with elementary functions, but we can find a series solution. Taylor series for tangent [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805660/formula-for-the-general-term-of-the-taylor-series-of-tanx-at-x-0)
$$\tan x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}4^k(4^k-1)B_{2k}}{(2k)!}x^{2k-1}$$
$$\sec^2 x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}4^k(4^k-1)(2k-1)B_{2k}}{(2k)!}x^{2k-2}$$
$$I=\int x^m\ln(x)\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}4^k(4^k-1)(2k-1)B_{2k}}{(2k)!}x^{2k-2}dx$$$$=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}4^k(4^k-1)(2k-1)B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\int x^{m+2k-2}\ln (x)dx$$$$=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}4^k(4^k-1)(2k-1)B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(\frac{x^{m+2k-1}\ln x}{m+2k-1}-\frac{x^{m+2k-1}}{(m+2k-1)^2}\right)$$
There is no way to continue forth, and no better answer

Comment: To play devil's advocate, did you apply the Risch algorithm to be *sure* there is no elementary antiderivative? (I don't think there's one either, but I didn't check...)